# How do I resolve the MADCATZ R.A.T 9 cursor bug in El Capitan?

Tags: mouse, bug, macos

As usual I wake up going to my computer playing some games. My mouse - a [MADCATZ R.A.T 9](http://store.madcatz.com/categories/mice-category/Mad-Catz-RAT-9-Wireless-Gaming-Mouse-for-PC-and-Mac.html) - is starting to be jerky and not working as I'd expect. Here is an example ---> [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGhAvdcaDj4&feature=youtu.be).

How do I salvage my morning pleasure?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem; though when I use USB Overdrive it sometimes fixes the issue (but not always).

Answer (score 1):

This helped to me:

> Update: I've loaded the Madcatz Software (for 10.9) against from here http://madcatz.com/downloads/ and now its working. No USB Overdrive or something like that installed, just the Madcatz software.
>   These are the steps you have to do:
>   Uninstall all other mouse drivers - USB-Overdrive, SteerMouse, Logitech, Razer, etc.
>   Restart.
>   Install the MadCatz driver/editor software.
>   Restart.
>   Add the Mad Catz Editor to the Accessibility permissions list. System Prefs -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility. Click the lock to authenticate then drag the Mad Catz Editor into the list to give it permissions.
>   Create/edit profiles and commands. Be sure to save the profile(s).
>   Use the menubar item to assign a profile to the mouse.
>   If it's not working, add that to your startup items:
>   /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/MadCatzSmartTechnology.app

[Discussion on Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7259305)
Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the startup screen (hold the option key) and see if the mouse is janky then.

If so, hardware issues.

If not, boot into safe mode (hold shift) and see if it's still janky.

If not, reboot normally.

This will at least let you know where the issue is. You can ask a follow on question once this troubleshooting is done.

Answer (score 0):

get usb overdrive (or wait for a mad driver update) and the hover effect comes back
http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html